# nodejs mysql query that relies on another query result and afterwards insert in loop the second query result to the first

Tags: mysql, node.js

i need to run a first query that i get from it a list of auctions, i need to run a second query that for each auction i get the lowest bid for this auction.
after i get the results i need to push the lowest bid to the auctions json that i recive from the first query (results1) in for loop.
when i console log results i get a array with 9 object (it should be 3) and the lowest bid property is only exists on 3 of them objects, it might be better way of doing this.
the console.log of results after adding it the lowest bids :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgvJI.jpg

```
router.get('/get-live-auctions', auth, (req, res) => {
  try {

    const userID = req.userData.userID;
    db.query(`SELECT auctions.UID,auctions.OriginCompany,auctions.DestinationCompany,auctions.OriginAddress,auctions.DestinationAddress,auctions.PickupDate,auctions.TotalWeight,auctions.StartDate,auctions.BidEndDate,auctions.AuctionEndDate,auctions.AuctionState,auctions.AuctionSerialNumber
    From auctions
    WHERE UserId='${userID}' AND AuctionState = 2 OR AuctionState = 3 OR AuctionState = 4`, (
      err, results, fields) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          let auctionsIDS = results[i].UID;
          db.query(`SELECT MIN(TotalPrice) AS lowestBid
          FROM bids
          Where AuctionID = '${auctionsIDS}'
          `, (err2, results2, fields2) => {
              let lowestBid = results2[0].lowestBid;
              results.lowestBid = lowestBid;
              console.log(results);
              if (err2) return res.send(error);
            }
          )
        }
        res.status(200).json(results);
      });

  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
})
```

how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you "need" to run two queries? Why not combine your requirements into one query? I recommend framing your question as asking about the problem rather than the attempted solution (see [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: I wrote what is the problem and what is the desired requirment and i gave the example so it would be easier to solve this, i also wrote that there might be a better solution

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow your requirements. What is the data you're retrieving? I see you've posted an image showing a console, but it's not easy to grasp exactly what's missing that should be there. I'm not sure enough information is provided to offer an answer.